# Javascript Counter - How to add more values

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am new to javascript and have come up with this counter 
Here is the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ep6s616z/
and below is the javascript

I'm trying to figure out how i could add more values so that it goes up to 20 on the counter tool. 
It **must** stay the same size, so how could i achieve this?

Would the new values be hidden and slide in?

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var pages = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];

$(document).ready(function () {
var num = 1;
updatePrice(num);});

function updatePrice(num) {
pages.forEach(function(entry) {

if (entry == num) {
     document.getElementById(entry).className = "page-selected page";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(entry).className = "page";
        }

        document.getElementById('circle').innerHTML = num });   

}


function addOne() {
var current = document.getElementsByClassName('page page-selected')[0].id

if (current < 8) {
    current++;
    updatePrice(current);
    }
}


function takeOne() {
var current = document.getElementsByClassName('page page-selected')[0].id
if (current > 1) {
    current--;
    updatePrice(current);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you check if it is the last visible number and arrow is clicked? Then just increment all the numbers, so it appears like it shifted.

Comment: note: You do not need all the separate onClick attribute handlers with jQuery. You can get the same effect using a single handler attached by jQuery. Much cleaner/simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a complete re-write as the events are far cleaner in pure jQuery. I also added an extra div to allow the scrolling you wanted:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ep6s616z/18/

Simpler HTML:

```
<div id="circle">1</div>
<div id="calculator">
    <div id="slider-left">-</div>
    <div id="slider">
        <div id="page-holder"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="slider-right">+</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
// Generate n items
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    $('#page-holder').append($('<div>').addClass('page').text(i));
}

// Outer slider - allows for scroller
var $slider = $('#slider');

// Actual page holding div
var $pageHolder = $('#page-holder');

// Listen for clicks on any .page divs
$pageHolder.on('click', 'div.page', function (e) {
    var $div = $(this);
    $('#page-holder .page').removeClass('page-selected');
    $div.addClass('page-selected');
    $('#circle').html($div.html());
    // Ensure the element is visible - of not scrill it into view
    var offset = $div.offset();

    // Range of the visible area
    var areaStart = $slider.scrollLeft();
    var areaEnd = areaStart + $slider.width();
    var x = ($div.index() + 1) * $div.outerWidth();
    if (offset.left > areaEnd)
    { 
        $slider.animate({scrollLeft: x}, 100);
    }
    else if (offset.left < areaStart)
    {
        $slider.animate({scrollLeft: x-$div.width()}, 100);
    }
});

$('#slider-right').click(function () {
    var $div = $('#page-holder .page-selected');
    if (!$div.length) {
        $div = $('#page-holder .page:first');
    } else {
        $div = $div.next();
    }
    $div.trigger('click');
});

$('#slider-left').click(function () {
    var $div = $('#page-holder .page-selected');
    if (!$div.length) {
        $div = $('#page-holder .page').last();
    } else {
        $div = $div.prev();
    }
    $div.trigger('click');
});
```

*Note: the scrolling to keep it in view is not perfect, as the range checks are not quite right,  but you need something to do.* :)

Comment: Thank you! This is what i was looking for and will help me alot! :)

Comment: Use it as a guide. There are several new techniques in there to research :)

Comment: I think you need to use styled buttons or links (and not divs) for the `+/-` as they wind up selecting text when you click them a lot (does not look nice).

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what u wanted . i have added a button control for adding the more limits on the slider.

**HTML code**

```
<input id="add" name="addmore" type="button" value="AddMore" />
```

**Jquery code:**

```
   $('#add').on('click', function () {
      var divEle = '<div onClick="updatePrice(this.id)" id="' + count + '" class="page">' + count + '</div>';
      $('#calculator').width($('#calculator').width() + sizeCounter);
      $('#page-holder').width($('#page-holder').width() + sizeCounter);
      $('#page-holder').append(divEle);
      pages[count - 1] = count;
      count++;
      if (count == 10) sizeCounter += 4;
  });
```

**Live Demo :**
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/ep6s616z/23/

Happy Coding :)